# Can I update existing apps in the app store if I have rejected my distribution certificate because I lost my private key?

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution, code-signing, private-key

I have done A LOT of looking around on the internet and just cannot find the answer to this question. I lost my private key, and so I have rejected and re-assigned new certificate/key combo, but am having issues submitting app updates to apps signed with the old key with my new key.

Is it possible to update an existing app with a newly replaced private key that is different than the one it was originally signed with?

Comment: This is a very good question.  Have you had any luck figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to submit app updates with a different distribution certificate. I've done it on multiple occasions. What specific issues are you having?

Comment: I am just about to attempt this too. I need to update an existing app but would like to create the bundle with my own distribution certificate. I'm concerned the existing app bundle ID would need to be the same though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, the bundle ID will need to be the same. I don't think Apple will let you upload an update with a different bundle ID.